# How can I get the child element in my css grid to work?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a 3 column grid with 2 rows to display my projects on my portfolio but they seem to only be populating the first column. I have tried and tried but I just don't know what to do to get it to work.

A picture showing how the files aren't lining up in columns:
[image]

How I want them to be:
[image]

**HTML/PHP**

```
    <div id="projects">
    <div class="project-item-container">

      <div class="project-item">
        <?php foreach ($projects as $projectItem) {?>

          <div class="project-item-img">
            <img class="absolute-center" src="assets/img/<?php echo $projectItem["img"]; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $projectItem["name"]; ?>">
          </div><!-- project item img end -->

          <div class="project-item-info">
            <h2><?php echo $projectItem["name"]; ?></h2>
            <h4><?php echo $projectItem["category"]; ?></h4>
          </div><!-- project item info end -->

        <?php } ?>

      </div><!-- project item end -->
    </div><!-- project-item container end -->
```

**CSS**

```
.project-item-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}

.project-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.project-item-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: it would be very helpful if you posted a codepen / jsfiddle

Comment: I was trying to but because of the PHP it won't work with either and I feel like the PHP is one of the reasons it might not be working.

Comment: It never occured to me that I could just view the page source and extract what the php spat out lol so I've done that and here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m2x3w7b8/

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS needs to look something like this ...

```
#projects {
  width: 92%;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.project-item-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 4rem;
}

.project-item img {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.project-item-info {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: How it rendered on my screen]

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise there was a property to centre things, I was just about to lose my mind figuring out how to centre it all!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the .project-item inside the forEach loop.
This site has great list of examples: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Omg this worked. I could cry, thanks! :)))))))))))))